# facing the problems with dns-api-go setup in google cloud

Tags: getdnsapi

I created the Ubuntu virtual machine on that I created the Go environment after that I successfully imported and installed the skx/dns-api-go

I followed this doc: https://github.com/skx/dns-api-go for to set up the environment also I installed the required dependencies like

> Dancer,Plack::Middle ware::Throttle::Lite,Net::DNS::Resolver,twiggy,
>   libdancer-perl ,libnet-cidr-lite-perl ,
>   libplack-middleware-reverseproxy-perl.

after that, at last, I run the following command:

```
dns-api-go  -redis-server localhost:6379
```

then am getting the following result :

> Launching the server on http://127.0.0.1:9999 redis: 2018/09/25
>   11:18:56 ring.go:263: ring shard state changed: Redis is down.

when I changed the port number in web preview in cloud shell it is showing as your server is not listing to 6379 port number, but in the instance level when I run the `netstat -an` command it is showing as the server is listing for 6379 port

please help me in resolving these issue.

Answer (score 0):

6379 is redis server port which is there for rate limiting feature. If you go through the main.go file, you'll see go server port is 9999. Just run "dns-api-go" command and hit http://localhost:9999/